# How do I programmatically convert a Keynote file to a PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint, keynote

Anyone know any good tools to convert a keynote file to a PowerPoint one?  We have an online tool that currently accepts PPT/PPTX files and we then use Aspose tools to do more with it. But we're needing to accept keynote files too and the easiest way in theory is to convert it to a PPT file and then process in the same way from there.

However we're really struggling to find a way to convert them programmatically!

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Old question but by the views counter seems relevant for many.. a conversion service such as CloudConvert can do the job (https://cloudconvert.com/api/conversions). At least for converting .key to .pptx (not sure about the other way round).

Comment: This isn't the place to post product advertising.